# Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Tags: android, gradle

I'm cloning to a github repository  and this error is apearing.

Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I also disable offline mode from github short cut method available on right side of android studio and sync again but it is not working again.[here is image of error and gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUVP9.png)

Comment: Clean the Project and then, Invalidate Cache and Restart .

Comment: clean project is not showing in build.